# Hide some system provided controls in AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, avplayerviewcontroller

I want to hide the rewind and forward buttons beside the play button in AVPlayerViewController. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Next time read the forum rules. This is not a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specifically hide those buttons. Its either hide everything or show everything using the method setShowsPlaybackControls. You can try using the contentOverlayView to manipulate them.